# Remote Kafka Consumer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-cluster

I have a 3-node Kafka cluster on another machine in which I cant connect and consume messages with Spring boot application remotely. I have changed my config file like this:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<myActual IP address>:9092
```

and here is my application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: :9092,:9093,:9094
      group-id: test-consumer-group
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

when I run the application, I got this error:

```
2020-10-26 12:47:52.524 WARN 4524 --- [| adminclient-1] 
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] 
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. 
Broker may not be available.
```

Comment: Your error says it's connecting to localhost, so why didn't you give the address for the other machine? Note: running 3 brokers on one machine is still a single point of failure and doesn't improve resilience or performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `bootstrap-servers: :9092,:9093,:9094`

You need to specify the host name or ip address.

`bootstrap-servers: some.host:9092,some.host:9093,some.host:9094`

Comment: I did but it's not working remotely, but it works with localhost properly.

Comment: Sorry for asking another question here, but did you manage to solve this problem? I am facing the same situation here.